# get cookies from DefaultHttpClient and pass to WebClient

Tags: java

I need to get the cookies from `DefaultHttpClient`, pass them to HtmlUnit's `WebClient`, and send a request.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.*;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

HttpClient apacheClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse apacheResponse;
HttpGet apacheGet;
WebClient htmlUnitClient = new WebClient();
WebRequest htmlUnitRequest;

HttpUriRequest hur = new HttpGet("http://..");
apacheResponse = apacheClient.execute(hur);
// Here I need to get cookies from apacheClient and set them for the next request done with htmlUnitClient
HtmlPage page = htmlUnitClient.getPage("http://..");
```

I would also like to keep the cookies within some kind of container. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean "send cookies"? Cookie is stored on the client's side so you don't need to set it again if it's the same client.

Comment: they're different clients but i already figured it out